# Can anything be done to make subprocess invocations faster in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have an executable written in C but don't have the source code. I can call in in python (in ubuntu linux):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# variable 'output' is the string I need.
p = Popen(["./excutable",par1,par2]], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
rc = p.returncode
```

This works fine for me except I need to do this millions of times. It takes a lot time to run. Is there a way to run this faster?

Thanks!

Comment: A "system call" is something else (specifically, it's the interface between the kernel and userland). That said, what you're doing here -- `fork()`ing and `exec()`ing a subprocess -- is inherently slow, no matter what language you implement it in. The best practice is to figure out **why** you're trying to do this millions of times, and find a way to avoid it -- maybe you change your `executable` so you can stream `par1` / `par2` pairs on its stdin and share a single instance.

Comment: something that could speed this up a slightly would be to put the executable on a fast/RAM disk. Loading would be faster. but you still have to spawn the process multiple times.

Comment: (now, one thing you *can* do is parallelize, and run several subprocesses at once; still, the best case improvement is that that'll be linear for the number of threads you can run, and in practice, it'll be less than linear as the processes contend with each other for resources).

Comment: also maybe you could feed more data to the same executable, and post-process it afterwards?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, shouldn't the OS block cache be providing equivalent performance? I wouldn't expect a ramdisk to speed up executable loading substantially on a system that's otherwise well-configured.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy probably. I used to do that on my amiga, but rhere were no disk cache. but on networked drives, you can never know.

Comment: @BoQiang, ...I'd suggest using `xargs -P` to try running instances in parallel in practice to measure where you get ideal throughput -- that way you can very quickly measure performance when your executable is invoked in parallel from shell before you go restructuring your Python.

Comment: (Even if you're being handed an executable, if this is important enough to be worth the dev time, executables *can* have be relinked with symbols replaced, or otherwise reverse-engineered and modified; someone handing you a precompiled binary doesn't by any means mean you're stuck with exactly what they give you).

Comment: Hmm. At least one potentially-available approach (dynamically linking and loading the executable *before* forking) depends on whether it was compiled to be position-independent code. However, that's all not-for-amateurs YMMV-style warranty-violating hackery anyhow.